# Rails 4 undefined method `any?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am running a chat application on my RoR app. I want to be able to render the user chat conversations from my layouts/application.html.erb to have the user chat conversations across all pages but the chat is only working when I run the index action method under my Users controller [class UsersController < ApplicationController]. When I have my chat on views/users/index.html.erb runs great. Just to make it available in all pages I created a render form under views/users called _chatlist.html.erb which has this line inside:

and rendered this form in my layouts/application.html.erb body as:
<%= render partial: 'users/chatlist' %>
 When I do that I get this error: undefined method `any?' for nil:NilClass.

How can I solve this nil issue? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: sorry, the code line inside  my form _chatlist.html.erb is <% if @conversations.any? %>

Comment: you need to pass `@conversations` into your partial.  

try `<%= render partial: 'users/chatlist', conversations: @conversations %>` and switch to `<% if conversations.any? %>` in the partial.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because `@conversations` is not initialized.
You have to write an method and call it in application_controller.rb if you want to make it available on all the pages. Your `application_controller.rb` should look like this.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :load_conversatios

  def load_conversatios
    # load you conversation here
    @conversations = Conversation.all
  end

end
```

And I think that is not a good approach to load all the conversations on all the pages. You have to make it available from ajax call.

Comment: The chat conversation is available from ajax call. I followed this tutorial. http://josephndungu.com/tutorials/gmail-like-chat-application-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: The idea is to have the chat conversation available when user moves from page to page in my app. Right now if user has a chatbox open in views/users/index.html.erb and moves to another page the conversation chatbox closes.